# How To Read and Load an Array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have provided the background info:
So we have are working on a project of creating Facebook Lite. And in it we have this array profiles[idx]; idx is the index number, nop is the number of profiles. There is a switch case for choosing options from the menu; the professor wants us that, when the user exits the program, it should save their profiles (profile consists of first name, last name, friends, age) and when the program loads, the code should be able to load all the profiles. It's complicated.

Here's my read/write code which doesn't seem to work. First, it just makes a file which has stuff like "Profile@21bcffb5" this written. Instead of First Name:, Last Name: etc (elements inside the array). Also it doesn't load the profiles and my program gets stuck in an endless loop.

```
public void write()
{
    try{
        PrintStream writer = new PrintStream( new File("ProfileData.txt"));
        for (int i=0; i<nop; i++){
            writer.println(profiles[idx]);
        }
        writer.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
public void read()
{
    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner ( new File("ProfileData.txt"));
        while(nop>0){
            System.out.println(profiles[idx]);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even make sense. Where did you declare nop and idx? Why are you basing logic on these inside of loops while not changing their values?

Comment: hello patstuart. I haven't posted the whole thing because it's very long. I have declared and initialized everything and my program works completely fine without the read and write things. It's just that our professor wants us to add read/write code and that's creating problems.

Comment: From what I can tell, that is your problem. You aren't incrementing the pointer, but using a global variable that didn't change, so you're reading the same line over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

It is printing the memory location at which `Profile` object is stored accessed by `profiles[idx]`. You should implement `toString()` method in `Profile` class which will print all the properties of the object

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried your method, but apparently it's writing the same stuff on the text document.

Comment: you can use ann explicit call to toString like this `writer.println(profiles[idx].toString())`